# 1980's Book/Short Story about tourists who visit another planet and are warned to stay on walkway

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I just recently remembered a book or short-story I read in the mid-80's (as a middle school student, I think) that was a scifi/fantasy about tourists who were able to travel to a foreign planet. Specifically I recall there being some warning about not touching anything and making sure to stay on the elevated walkway/path. Of course, someone doesn't and there are huge consequences (I think it might have had strong environmentalist/butterfly effect overtones). It was a bit of a morality tale as well if I remember correctly.

Any help in identifying it would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: It's not on another planet, but are you thinking of [A Sound of Thunder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sound_of_Thunder) by Ray Bradbury?

Comment: This one? https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v06n04_1954-01#page/n5/mode/2up

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: The aspect of "don't leave the path!" sounds a bit like the movie [Stalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalker_(1979_film)) based on the novel [Roadside Picnic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadside_Picnic).

Comment: Sorry everyone, I was AFK! Let me poke around some of the leads and I'll report back. Thx!

Comment: @user14111 Wow, that sounds very much like it, except I don't recall all the hunting. lol. I was convinced it was not until the bit about the butterfly. Hmmm...I want to dig a little more.

Comment: @Alfe, I'll check out Roadside Picnic, but I think user14111 has got it.

Comment: @user14111, It is so crazy that i don't remember the time travel, the dinosaurs nor the hunting, but everything else fits: the path, the warning, the butterfly (although I didn't know it was a literal butterfly). I remember as a kid fixating on the accidental nature of falling off the path. Of course, I also didn't remember (nor apparently catch at the time) that the path was "levitating." Anyway, I'm going to mark this answered...well, I'm not really sure how to do that yet, but anyway, THANKS! It was really bugging me. You all are AWESOME!

Comment: @user14111, I am convinced you nailed it. So, are you going to submit your suggestion as an "answer"? I started to hit the "Answer Your Question" button, but didn't want to take credit for your insight. I'll check back later and if that's not how it works I'll go ahead and submit your answer to satisfy my need for closure.THANK YOU AGAIN! (And anyone else who gave it any thought!)

Comment: @Daddie0 You're welcome! It was easy to guess because it's a very famous story which [has come up many times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5Dis%3Aanswer+bradbury+sound+thunder). If you're sure it's the right answer, we can close your question as a duplicate. By the way, here's a [bibliograph](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61488) of books that story has appeared in; maybe you will recognize one of [the covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?61488). Welcome to the site, hope you have more questions for us.